# Understanding the sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, sizeof

```
char c = 'A';
printf("%d\n",sizeof(c));// output = 1
printf("%d\n",sizeof('A')); // output = 4
```

Why the `sizeof` operator gives different output for same character? Please Help

Comment: Because 'A' doesn't have a type.  It's being interpreted as an `int`.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer it does have a type, and the type is `int`

Comment: Fair enough.  Since 'A' isn't cast in any way it is an `int` by definition.  I was focused more on the fact that there was a difference in how they were defined.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as an expression without a type ... what a weird concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`c` is a variable of type `char`; its size is 1 byte.

`'A'` is an `int` literal - don't ask me why the standard says that. Its size is 4 bytes on your platform (the same as `sizeof(1)`).

Comment: Back in the very olden days,  people used multibyte characters, like 'xy'. The PDP11 UNIX code had a lot of that stuff. It mostly went away when they ported C to bigendian machines. C++ fixed this ... character constants are chars. This is one of the few ways in which C is not a proper subset of C++.